# Need help changing Java code into a method addText (String text)

Tags: java, android

I have a homework assignment for my study Android application development that I need help with, I am only a beginner.
In my code (I did not write it, its a part of the study) in the methods onCreate, onSrart, onRestart, onResume, onPause, onStop I repeat the following line each time:

```
ausgabe += "First Activity - \"onStart\" durchlaufen\"n;

tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
```

My assignment is to store these two lines in a method addText(String text) so that each time I will only invoke this method instead of using the repetition.
My question is how do I do this? A pseudocode will be very helpful.
I thank you in advance for any help or information and here is my code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
    {
        private String ausgabe = "";
        public TextView tvAnzeige;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
            Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.second_activity);
            button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());
            tvAnzeige = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.anzeige);
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity - \"onCreate\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart()
        {
            super.onStart();
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity - \"onStart\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\"onResume\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause()
        {
            super.onPause();
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\"onPause\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop()
        {
            super.onStop();
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\"onStop\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestart()
        {
            super.onRestart();
            ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\"onRestart\" durchlaufen\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

        //inner listener class
        class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                ausgabe += "Button \"second Activity\" geklickt\n";
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                try
                {
                    FirstActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
                {
                    ausgabe += anfe.toString() + "\n";
                    tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific. also, += appends or adds to the string. if you want to reset each time the set the ausgabe = "my string" each time a lifecycer method is called

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand you.

Comment: the question is very unclear. please details exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please explain what u want more clearly

Comment: You mean simply 'put the lines in a privat method, replace the variable part of the String constant with variable text and replace the execution of the lines with the method call'?

Comment: Your assignment asks you to define one single additional method, that takes a string argument; then the method is supposed to pull together a message string and call another method. That is like really really essential basic Java stuff. If this assignment is already "too much for your" to get it worked out yourself ... my my. In other words: **try** something yourself. As of you now, you are asking **other** people to do your homework for you. Even if you get an answer, you will learn **nothing** from that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is "do my homework for me style"; without showing any evidence that the person asking the question tried anything to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        addText("FirstActivity - \"onStart\" durchlaufen\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        addText("FirstActivity -\"onResume\" durchlaufen\n");
    }

    ... (more methods) 


    void addText(final String text) {
        ausgabe += text;
        tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: if you are already doing his homework for him; at least go the full nine yards and avoid **all** code duplication ...

Comment: @Jägermeister LOL, I can't do the final duplication into the homework program code.

Comment: @mjn  that was very helpful! I appreciate it a lot since now I can see how it can work with the Java code, as I have mention I am a beginner and you are a very good teacher! for the rest of the users, why are you even writing a comment if you do not show intention of wanting to help and just been a typical trolls?!

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward, unless there are more requirements to your assignment. But since this is a homework assignment, try to answer it and we can assist you in a way that helps you learn. The general idea is that you will create a method which will perform the actions outlined.

Lets say you have a helloworld class, and you want to repeatedly call a method along with some information.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){
        greetMe("Bill");
   }

   public static void greetMe(String name){
       System.out.println( String.format("Hello %s", name));
  } 
}
```

This would output 
**Hello Bill**

You can apply the same concept to your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 private String ausgabe = "";
 public TextView tvAnzeige;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.second_activity);
     tvAnzeige = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.anzeige);

     button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());
     ausgabe += "FirstActivity - \"onCreate\" durchlaufen\n";
     tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
 }

  private void addText(String text){
     ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\""+text+"\" durchlaufen\n";
     tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStart()
 {
     super.onStart();
     addText("onStart");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume()
 {
     super.onResume();
     addText("onResume");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     addText("onPause");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop()
 {
     super.onStop();
     addText("onStop");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onRestart()
 {
     super.onRestart();
     addText("onRestart");
 }

 class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
 {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
         ausgabe += "Button \"second Activity\" geklickt\n";
         Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
         try
         {
             FirstActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
         } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
         {
             ausgabe += anfe.toString() + "\n";
             tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
         }
     }
 }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer and thank you to those that helped me ones again:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
private String ausgabe="";
public TextView tvAnzeige;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    Button button =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.second_activity);
    button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());
    tvAnzeige =(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.anzeige);
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onCreate\" durchlaufen\n");
    //ausgabe += "FirstActivity - \"onCreate\" durchlaufen\n";
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);

}
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onStart\" durchlaufen\n");
    //ausgabe += "FirstActivity - \"onStart\" durchlaufen\n";
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onResume\" durchlaufen\n");
    //ausgabe += "FirstActivity -\"onResume\" durchlaufen\n";
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onPause\" durchlaufen\n");
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onStop\" durchlaufen\n");
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}
@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    addText("FirstActivity - \"onRestart\" durchlaufen\n");
    //tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}
public void addText(String text){
    ausgabe += text;
    tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
}

//inner listener class
class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        addText("Button \"second Activity\" geklickt\n");
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        try {
            FirstActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            ausgabe += anfe.toString() + "\n";
            tvAnzeige.setText(ausgabe);
        }

    }
}}
</code>
```